# How to concatenate values of all rows in a dataframe into a single row without altering the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame input that looks like:

> ```
>   col1 col2 col3
> 0    3    1  NaN
> 1  NaN    7    8
> ```

How to collapse *all* rows while concatenating the data in the rows with `', '`?

The desired data frame output:

> ```
>   col1  col2 col3
> 0    3  1, 7    8
> ```

---

Sample input code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = {'col1': ["3", np.nan], 'col2': ["1", "7"], 'col3': [np.nan, "8"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`agg` + `dropna` + `str.join` comes to mind.

```
df.agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())).to_frame().T

  col1  col2 col3
0    3  1, 7    8
```

There are other solutions, my peers will find them for you :)

Comment: This does it, thanks a lot! Out of curiosity any simple solution for it to work with data of type `[None, 3, None]`? Right now it raises error `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index col1')`.

Comment: @Nae You could add a step before this: `df = df.astype(str).replace('nan', np.nan)`...

Answer (score 5):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[
        ', '.join(map(str, map(int, filter(pd.notna, c))))
        for c in zip(*df.values)
    ]], columns=df.columns
)

  col1  col2 col3
0    3  1, 7    8
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to get what you want would be to create a new dataframe with the same columns as your old dataframe, and populate the first index with your desired data. In your case, your desired data would be a list of each column, joined by `', '`, and with your `NaN` values removed:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for col in df.columns:
    new_df.loc[0, col] = ', '.join(df[col].dropna().tolist())

>>> new_df
  col1  col2 col3
0    3  1, 7    8
```

Answer (score 4):

With stack

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).apply(','.join).to_frame().T
Out[163]: 
  col1 col2 col3
0    3  1,7    8
```

Answer (score 3):

One more option:

```
In [156]: pd.DataFrame([[df[c].dropna().astype(int).astype(str).str.cat(sep=', ') 
                         for c in df]], 
                       columns=df.columns)
Out[156]:
  col1  col2 col3
0    3  1, 7    8
```