# Python Loop for Multiple Row String Concatination

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to create a loop in python that will concatenate multiple rows of strings together. I have created the table that I have now listed as "Before" and then the table I am trying to create "After". Any thoughts on how to do this? I am currently using the following code to get just one string but I need to be able to loop the entire data frame:

```
df.str.cat(sep='')
```

Before:

```
Text       |    Channel  |  Destination   | Amount  | Total
string1           NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN
string2           DKI           US             34       5   
string3           NaN           NaN           NaN      NaN
string4           DKI           CA             39       20
```

After:

```
Text           |    Channel  |  Destination   | Amount  | Total
string1string2        DKI           US            34       5
string3string4        DKI           CA            39       20
```

Comment: Please show your current attempts, and clarify the logic by which you want to concatenate the strings (why do `All` and `purpose` go together, for instance?)

Comment: @sacul I am trying to just concatenate strings. I have updated the tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate values of all rows in a dataframe into a single row without altering the columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342769/how-to-concatenate-values-of-all-rows-in-a-dataframe-into-a-single-row-without-a)

Comment: But what tells us that `string1` and `string2` go together?

Comment: @sacul The way to determine string1 and string2 go together is concatenating everything from the NaN down to where the first number is. Then especially restarting the concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

Create helper `Series` by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html), check non NaNs by [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) and create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

Then aggregate dy dict of functions, remove index name and for same columns order add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
a = df['total'].shift().notna().cumsum()
#for oldier pandas versions
#a = df['total'].shift().notnull().cumsum()
d = {'row':'first', 'total':'last', 'Text':''.join}

df = df.groupby(a).agg(d).rename_axis(None).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   row            Text  total
0    1  string1string2    3.0
1    3  string3string4    1.0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston - I test it with multiple NaNs

Comment: Gotcha.  I see. I knew there was a reason you're doing it that way.  Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael What is I have multiple metrics to group and then also multiple text columns?

Comment: @jumpman23 - Then change aggregate dictionary like `d = { 'Text':''.join, 'Channel':'last', 'Destination':'last', 'Amount':'last', 'Total':'last'}`

Comment: @jezrael Doesn't a in your code need to be adjusted as well?